# how can I access a .java file from another project and package?

Tags: java, import, package

I have two projects

```
D:\Project_A\src...
D:\Project_B\src...
```

now I want to access a Java file from Project_B via Project_A.

I would appreciate if the solution that does not involve any clicking in the IDE, because it should be IDE independent.

ie.:

```
package Project_A
import Project_B.src.test.meow.wuff.MyClass

MyClass x = new MyClass();
```

Comment: jar it and include it in the classpath of the project you need it

Comment: Export your project as a JAR and add the JAR to Project_A's classpath

Comment: the project is a Selenium - Maven project and I cannot build a .jar. But since my question gets downvoted, i stop asking anything special here... thanks for your reply though

Answer (score 9):

You can build a `Jar` file from the first project and add it to the build path of the second project. Then you can use all the code from the first project. More information about this can be found [here.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/)

Comment: this link would improve your answer http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/